# removeFromSuperview is not removing view. But the view doesn't exists in (self.view.subviews)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, rubymotion

I really need your help. Because "`removeFromSuperview`" is not removing view. But the view doesn't exists in (self.view.subviews).

mycode(rubymotion)

```
@back_view = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRectMake(0, 0, boundsSize.width, boundsSize.height))
self.view.addSubview(@back_view)

p "A #{self.view.subviews}"

@back_view.removeFromSuperview

p "B #{self.view.subviews}"
```

console

```
A
[PXUITableView_UITableView:0xd3be600, PXUIView_UIView:0x10cc7c30]

B
[PXUITableView_UITableView:0xd3be600]
```

so, `removeFromSuperview` is working. but not removing view.

why??

Comment: Log the view @back_view after the last log of the subviews to check if it is nil. Also check log its' .superview to see if it still has one.

Comment: is `self.view` of `UIView` type, or is it a custom view? `addSubview:` behavior may have been overridden.

Answer (score 1):

After init method, p @back_view to get @back_view instance pointer, and after removeFromSuper p @back_view and @back_view.superView. If @back_view instance pointer not in log of subviews before remove or @back_view.superView not nil, maybe you create more than one view with same frame;